# Use copy from windows diplaying the status form

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

with delphi, what i can display the form that display when i start a copy?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  shfileop: TSHFileOpStruct;
begin
  shfileop.Wnd := Handle;
  shfileop.wFunc := FO_COPY;
  shfileop.pFrom := PChar('C:\myfile.txt'#0);
  shfileop.pTo := PChar('C:\Copy of myfile.txt'#0);
  shfileop.fFlags := 0;
  SHFileOperation(shfileop);
end;
```

Comment: note that the #0 is needed because this api receives double terminated strings so that multiple filenames can be passed.

Comment: Thanks :) I have read too something more to msdn about TSHFileOpStruct and it is very much interesting.

Comment: i define Handle as THandle, but what value i need assign it? Delphi XE2 warning me telling that not is initialized. Is correct if i set it to 0? or i need get some value for it?

Comment: No it's not a THandle, it's a window handle, HWND. Use `MainForm.Handle`. This should be a comment to Andreas' answer, not an answer in its own right.

Comment: Ok understood now, in this moment i using console application for test, so what i can write to place of mainform.handle? thanks again.

Comment: Well, pass 0 in that case. You could hunt for the window handle of your console but 0 will likely be fine.